# Where do voltages come from in solutions?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electrochemistry

I have a clear understanding about how you can use thermodynamics to show that different electrode-solution pairs exist at different electric potentials...

One can go through a few equations and easily arrive at $\Delta G=nFE$.

That's all good and fine. You can make some solutions and measure things with a volt meter, and your measurements will line up with thermodynamic predictions.

And that's great! But how can you arrive at the same conclusion from an electromagnetic standpoint? What is (electrically) happening to create these different electric potentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from a standpoint in chemistry, I would suggest that there is some degree of disassociation or ionization in most of the solutions, which would create positive and negative ions, and hence an electric potential.